# EJS File having trouble finding script file after converting JS project to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, directory-structure

Folder structure:

- root:

  - dist:

    - FOLDER 'models' (models for mongoose/mongodb)
    - this is also where I store the Typescript compiled JS files, such as script.js.
  - src

    - FOLDER 'models' files to be compiled for mongoose models
    - FOLDER 'assets' (photos, thumbnails, etc)
    - FOLDER 'css' (for the entire project)
    - This is where these files live: server.ts, script.ts, and other misc scripting files that all get compiled by typescript.
  - FOLDER 'views':

    - EJS layouts and body files. For example, layout.ejs and home.ejs (body of layout.ejs)
  - also at root are: package-lock.json, .env, .gitignore, package.json, and tsconfig.json

**Now onto the problem i'm facing...**

I'm very new to Typescript but was able to convert many of these files including server.js and script.js (the main two files of this program) to Typescript. They currently have no errors pre-compilation, but the home.ejs file (in views) can not find the script.js file.

**When using  in my ejs files, should i aim to the script.js that has been compiled down?** Or should I aim to the script.ts in my src folder? I was able to link to the script.js but when I converted the file to TS, the EJS file can no longer find it in browser.

Here is the code that is relevant for my home.ejs file:

```
<body>

 <script src="/dist/script.js"></script>
 <script src="/launch.js"></script>

</body>
```

And here is a screenshot, if it helps, of my current structure:
[Image of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVt6J.jpg)

For the  line, I have tried all of these but they don't work:

```
<script src="/dist/script.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/script.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/script.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/script.js"></script>
```

Also knowing if node should run the server.js (compiled) file or the server.ts (uncompiled) would be helpful!